# Replace last word in string with another string

Tags: c#, console-application

```
string str="My name is abc"
string name="logan"
```

I want to replace 'abc' with string name in console application c#.

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: There are several ways to do this, depending on your exact need. Could you elaborate a little on what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Set the String `str` to `"My name is {0}`, then you can say `str = String.Format(str, name)`

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can't make changes in your string:

```
string str = "My name is abc";
string name = "logan";
    
int lastIndex = str.LastIndexOf(" ");
if (lastIndex > 0) {
    str = str.Substring(0, lastIndex + 1) + name;
}

Console.WriteLine (str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `String.Format`-Function.

There you can replace fragments inside a String with a value you choose:

```
string str = "My name is {0}"; // the {n} defines the parameter-index, you can add as many parameters you want: {0}, {1}, {2}, ...
string name = "Logan"; // your input

string replace = String.Format(str, name) // multiple parameters possible

Console.WriteLine(replace);
// My Name is Logan
```